# After update form all dialog are refreshed Primefaces JSF

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm try to add Dialog dynamically via code means onClick and it showing only when refreshing the form but its refreshing all the dialogs, all the dialogs field are cleared everything is become new

how can i show dialog without refreshing form?

Its data entry form, want to open multiple forms at a time.

thanks

```
UIComponent component = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("webForm");
    if (component != null) {
        int count = countDialog(component.getChildren()) + 1;
        Dialog tp = new Dialog();
        tp.setVisible(true);
        tp.setWidgetVar("widget" + count);
        component.getChildren().add(tp);

        RequestContext request = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        request.update("webForm");
    }
```

***index.xhtml***

```
<p:menuitem value="New Dialog" actionListener="#{dialogsView.addDialog}", update="webForm"/>
```

Comment: Because you're updating the whole form that's wy

Comment: but how can i show only new added dialog?

Comment: I found the solution, its in setRendered method, thanks